# How to tell the if the City is incorrect in OpenWeatherMap api and in android

Tags: android, json, weather-api, openweathermap

I am creating an app which will tell the weather condition of a city using the OpenWeatherMap.org api. In this app I let user to write a city name and the data will be fetched from the web. But what if the user entered wrong city.

For example if a user entered Lomdon instead of London.

What should I do in that case. The Api I am using is 
"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city name

Thanks in advance for the help, I am new to android development.

Comment: you can show him the error message while you parse json , but prefer don't let mistakes happen (add auto complete , list with all cities  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the city is incorrect your API returns an error message. You can check it like this:

"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Lomdon"

```
    try {
        String msg = jsonObject.getString("message");
        if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Error: Not found city")) {
            Log.e("TAG", "City not found");
        } else {
            // Use the data
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The reason I didn't use `cod` which looks like the return code, is that if the city is found `cod` is an int and if it's not found it's a string. Kind of misleading to design the JSON like that.